# Number of ways to arrange a tournament of 8 people

Tags: combinations

If you are arranging a 1vs1 tournament of 8 people, how many different ways can you arrange the first round? A set of pairings is different if someone has a different opponent. For example, you can arrange a tournament of 4 as follows: $\{AvB, CvD\}$, $\{AvC, BvD\}$, ${AvD, BvC\$} = 3 different ways this can be arranged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first round of the tournament can be arranged in
$\frac{8!}{2^4}=2520$ ways

The first contestant can be chosen in $8$ ways, for each of those choices, there are $7$ choices for the second contestent of the pair.
But this way, we have counted all pairs twice, because we have counted the pair $(AB)$ as the contestant $A$ first and the pair $(BA)$ as the contestant $A$ second in the pair. So the total number of choices for the first pair is $\frac{8\cdot 7}{2}=28$.

A more general result states that from $n$ elements you can take
$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!(n-1)!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ subsets of two elements.
ie there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pairs.

If we have $n=2m$ contestants total, I claim there are $\frac{n!}{2^m}$ ways to organise the first round.
The proof is by induction. For $n=2$ it is clear.
The first pair can be chosen in $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways.
For each of those choices, we are left with $n-2=2(m-1)$ contestants,
by induction the rest of the pairs can be organised in
$\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{m-1}}$ ways.
This means the total number of possible arrangements for the first round are
$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{m-1}}=\frac{n!}{2^m}$

If the number of contestants were odd, $n=2m+1$, you can aply similar arguements and find that again there are $\frac{n!}{2^m}$ ways to roganise the first round

Aplying that for $n=8=2\cdot 4$
gives for the first round $\frac{8!}{2^4}=\frac{40320}{16}=2520$
possible ways.

Edit: Corrected a BIG mistake I did and gave a general formula

Comment: Is the general pattern to arrange a tournament of $n$ people just $(n-1)*(n-3)*(n-5)*...$

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I just realised I made a mistake. There are not only $(n-1)$ ways to choose the first pair, because there are also $n$ ways to coose the first person of the pair, and all that double counts all pairs. The correct answer is the first pair can be chosen in $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}$. I will edit the answer to correct it

Comment: The explanation and example at the end of the question indicate that the OP wants to consider only who plays against whom, not the order in which the games are played. For example, $\{C\lor D,A\lor B\}$ is not listed as a different arrangement from $\{A\lor B,C\lor D\}$. Your 2520 counts each of the desired arrangements $24$ times, because the $4$ games can be played in $4!$ orders. So I think the answer the OP wants is $105$ ($=2520/24)$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Yes, you are absolutely right. The correct number for the general case is then $\frac{n!} {2^m m!} $